# How to play youtube video while mixing with background music?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, avaudiosession

I have an app that is used in the gym. The user may want to watch a video demonstrating an exercise without stopping the music they are playing through Spotify or some other app.

I used to do with with a `UIWebView`, and mix the audio in `AVAudioSession`, but I can't do this with `WKWebView`. `WKWebView` takes over the audio session and stops whatever else is playing, then it doesn't restart the audio it stopped.

My question is, what other ways can I play the Youtube video in my app without stopping the background music? or if it must stop, at least be able to restart the background music.

Music stopping at the gym and being forced to go out of the app to restart it is terrible user experience.

Also, please note that going back to `UIWebView` is not an option, as Apple is deprecating this class.